# How to read files to list of dataframes based on string matching R

Tags: r

I want to take a list of files

```
list = c('one.apple.txt',
'one.orange.txt',
'two.apple.txt', 
'two.orange.txt', 
'three.apple.txt', 
'three.orange.txt')
```

and, based on string matching, read them efficiently into a list of dataframes separated by 'one', 'two' and 'three', with the columns in each df 'apple' and orange'. Each file is one column, and should be appended to each other as columns.
Essentially what I need is:

```
List of 3
 $ one:'data.frame':    109514 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ apple      : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ orange     : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ two:'data.frame':    109514 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ apple        : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ orange     : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ three:'data.frame':  109514 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ apple        : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ orange     : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

So far, I have done this inefficiently by doing:

```
list_dfs = list()
for (i in 1:length(list)){
    number = strsplit(list[i], ".", fixed = T)[[1]][1]
    fruit = strsplit(list[i], ".", fixed = T)[[1]][2]
    df = read.table(list[i], header = F, sep = '\t', stringsAsFactors = F)
    df_col = df$V1
    list_dfs =  append(list_dfs, list(df_col))
    names(list_dfs)[[i]] = paste0(number,"_",fruit)       
}
```

Which gives me

```
List of 6
 $ one_apple        : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ one_orange     : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ two_apple        : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ two_orange    : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ three_apple    : num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ three_orange: num [1:109514] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

And then:

```
master_df = data.frame(matrix(unlist(list_dfs), nrow = max(lengths(list_dfs))))
colnames(master_df) = names(list_dfs)
master_df = sapply(c("one","two","three"),
      function(x) master_df[startsWith(names(master_df),x)], simplify = FALSE)
```

This gives me what I want but I have a feeling this can be done more efficiently. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines. The code will read csvs into a list of `data.frames`, and then put them into one large `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyverse)

c('one.apple.txt',
  'one.orange.txt',
  'two.apple.txt', 
  'two.orange.txt', 
  'three.apple.txt', 
  'three.orange.txt') %>%
  map(
    ~read_csv(.x) # this will probably need to be finetuned
  ) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "file_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `fread` from `data.table` to read this faster

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- setNames(lapply(list, fread), sub("\\.txt", "", list))
```

and convert it to a single dataset with `rbindlist`

```
dat <- rbindlist(lst1, idcol = "file_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way in the tidyverse.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

# put the location of your files here...
file_location <- "your/folder/with/the/files"

file_names <- list('one.apple.txt',
                   'one.orange.txt',
                   'two.apple.txt', 
                   'two.orange.txt', 
                   'three.apple.txt', 
                   'three.orange.txt')

# this will load in all the data, stacking them with a column name saying what file they are from
data <- map_dfr(set_names(file_names),
                ~ read.table(file.path(file_location, .x), header = F, sep = '\t', stringsAsFactors = F),
                .id = "file_name")

# split the file name for the df and column name
# then split on the df name
# then pivot into a list from the columns and unnest the list
data %>% 
  separate(file_name, c("df", "col"), extra = "drop") %>%
  split(.$df) %>% 
  map( ~ .x %>% 
         select(-df) %>% 
         pivot_wider(names_from = "col", values_from = "V1", values_fn = list) %>% 
         unnest(everything()))
```